# Reload external .yml file in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, yaml

I need to reload the external .yml file in Spring Boot.

I able to achieve this from .properties file by following example.

https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-boot-modules/spring-boot-properties

I am not able to achieve this with .yml file.

Could anyone can help on this.

Comment: Look at this SO answer: [Commons Configuration2 ReloadingFileBasedConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40735676/1065953)